# How to retrieve individual tags from TAGS column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in MySQL database:

```
id    creation_date                         score     tags
1     2016-02-09 07:24:59.097000+00:00      -1        html|javascript
2     2016-02-09 08:10:00.000000+00:00      0         xml|css
3     2016-02-10 08:00:15.000000+00:00      2         html|javascript
4     2016-02-11 07:00:45.000000+00:00      -5        html|css
```

I want to retrieve the tags and order them by scores. Then I want to sort the tags by the frequency of negative scores, so that the worst tags would appear on top.

The expected result for the above-given query would be:

```
TAG          FREQUENCY
html         2
css          1
javascript   1
xml          0
```

I get stuck with the retrieval of individual tags from columns.

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE score < 0
```

Comment: [How to count occurences in comma separated column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985465/how-to-count-occurences-in-comma-separated-column/32985910#32985910) as a starting point

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: The query provided in the accepted answer is very complicated and it is not explained at all. Therefore thanks for the link, but I am waiting that someone explains in details how to solve my task.

Comment: The only valid answer is to redesign your schema to 3NF. Storing tags as CSV(| - delimited) is poor design.

Comment: @ScalaBoy . . . Why are you storing multiple values in a single column?  That is not the SQL way to store things.  SQL has a great ways of storing lists -- it is called a table, not a string column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: This is how the data is stored in Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow). Take a look at the table "post_questions". So, this question should not be addressed to me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are stuck with such an awful data format, you can do something with it.  A table of numbers can help, but here is an example that will extract up to the first 3 items:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(tags, '|', n.n), '|', -1) as tag, count(*)
from (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 as n union all
      select 3 as n
     ) n join
     t
     on n.n <= length(tags) - length(replace(t.tags, '|', '')) + 1
group by tag;
```

What is this doing?  The `on` clause is making sure there are at least `n` tags in the string, for a given value of `n` (larger values are filtered out).

The two `substring_index()` functions are extracting the nth tag from the list.  And then there is aggregation.

Comment: What happens if there are 4 tags? Will it handle the 3rd and 4th tags as a single tag?

Comment: You need to extend the `n` subquery to handle the maximum number of tags.